# Trying to websrap with python, pypeteer

Tags: python, discord.py, pyppeteer

Goal is to pull the information off of a website that tracks tiktok followers and post it in console/send in discord channel. Currently using discord to initiate it but having it print in console. Current code listed below prints:

> [<pyppeteer.element_handle.ElementHandle object at 0x00000214B2703640>]

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    statspage = await browser.newPage()
    await statspage.goto('https://livecounts.io/tiktok-live-follower-counter/charlieputh')
    t = await statspage.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
    print(t)
```

I would like it to return with the amount of followers listed on that page. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page.xpath` function gives you elements' list, not text.
If you want to get text of element you need to evaluate it, like:

```
elements = await statspage.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
text = await page.evaluate("e => e.innerText", elements[0])
```

As you might know, pyppeteer is an unofficial Python version of puppeteer, so you should see [documentation of puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) to see how it works. And also [docs of pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/) to see what are differences in Python version.